# Is this a circular dependency in Python?

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I'm making a command line interface in Python.

The class named Application holds the command classes derived from the command base in a list. The problem is that one of the commands (help command) needs a list of all the other commands. And because of this, if I access the list in the application class, where I include the command classes derived from "CommandBase" class, from within a command class, will there be a circular dependecy ?

Here is the very simplified version of my code:

```py
class Application:
    commands: list[CommandBase]

    def add_command(self, cmd):
        self.commands.append(cmd)

    def main_loop(self):
        # execute commands according to user input
        while True:
            readln = input("> ")
            # find command by the name
            command.execute()

class CommandBase:
    
    def get_name() -> str:
        pass

class CommandHelp(CommandBase):
    
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def get_name():
        return "help"

    def execute(self):
        # print command list
        print(",".join(self.app.commands))


# create instances
app = Application()
random_cmd = CommandRandom()
help_cmd = CommandHelp()

# add commands
app.add_command(random_cmd)
app.add_command(help_cmd)
```

Comment: Yes it's circular, but why would that be a problem?

Comment: Many people say it's a design problem and I should be not doing my designs using that kind of architectures.

Comment: Where would the circular dependency be? `Application` depends on `CommandHelp`, but `CommandHelp` won't depend on `Application`?

Comment: There's a reference cycle, but no circular dependency. Creating an `Application` instance does not require any instances of `CommandBase`, even if creating an instance of` CommandHelp` requires an instance of `Application`.

Comment: So, you're telling the constructors of the both class should require each other. In the places where I researched Circular Dependency, this situation was not clearly explained. Thank you very much for your answer.